# When does Poopy the Bird come to drop poop on people?

Tags: happy-street

I have a mission from Zoe to drop poop from Poopy the Bird onto my citizens. However, I have not seen it yet. When does it arrive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bird will fly by once in a while at random, there's no set time and no way to make it appear. Look for something that resembles a seagull flying over your little town, and tap on it to fire away.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to *make* him come, you have to wait and he will come randomly. But here is a tip: When he does come, as you tap on him to make poop fall, he increases speed. So be sure to tap quickly if you want to get him to poop enough! **CLICK FAST.**

Answer (score 0):

He comes at random times and nothing you can do to make him appear. Once you see a FLYING BIRD click on it to drop poop on your citizens.

Answer (score -1):

When you see a sea Like gull you need to tap on it to make it poop if you want a lot of poop tap it millions of times

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers :\